# Fancybox 3 doesn't want to display lightbox image in microsoft Edge and IE

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, fancybox, gallery, lightbox

Fancybox runs great in chrome, safari and firefox, but when i try to click a thumbnail in Edge or IE for that matter, i get the message, "content can not be displayed, please try again later.

This is my image line a shown in the fancybox setup guide;

```
div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row catimg">
            <div class="col-sm-12"> <a data-type="fancybox" data-fancybox="gallery" href="afbeeldingen/trapauto.jpg"><img src="afbeeldingen/trapauto.jpg"></a> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

It is for a bootstrap project

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.0.47/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE**
After another check, it appears to only work locally and not on a server.

Comment: Show your JS code and version you are using for FancyBox and jQuery. Do you have any errors in the console in IE/Edge on page load or after clicking?

Comment: This problem typically occurs if working locally due to security policy. So, are you developing locally or you have uploaded your files to webserver?

Comment: @Janis I develop locally but also test it on a server now and again. I checked again, and locally works fine, but on server not...

Comment: @makshh I added the versions, but no extra JS was required... as i mentioned in other reply, it only works locally, not on server...  Could this be because of server restrictions?

Comment: Check path of your image, maybe try to use absolute path, e.g, href="/path/to/image.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @janis, the lightbox image should be linked in an absolute path: `<a href="http://website.com/image.jpg"` instead of `<a href="image.jpg"`